# How to get email address from facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

I have two websites and two Facebook apps for them. Now I'm working on the second site, and I try to get user email address after login with Facebook. But what's working on the other site, that doesn't work on this.
Here's my code:

```
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '****************','******************************' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://mywebsite.com/fbconfig.php' );
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?locale=en_US&fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,gender,locale' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
        $fbemail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
        $fbfirst = $graphObject->getProperty('first_name');
        $fblast = $graphObject->getProperty('last_name');
        $fbgender = $graphObject->getProperty('gender');
        $fblocale = $graphObject->getProperty('locale');
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $fbemail;
        $_SESSION['FIRST'] = $fbfirst;           
        $_SESSION['LAST'] = $fblast;
        $_SESSION['GENDER'] =  $fbgender;
        $_SESSION['LOCALE'] =  $fblocale;
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/
  header("Location: index.php?uid=log-in");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl( array('scope' => 'email'));
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
```

I've not even got an email address on the following line:

```
$fbemail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
```

Thank you for any help or idea.

Comment: Did the users get asked for the permission during login?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine, but I can't able to store email address in database. The query doesn't works because of the empty email... When I take it off, it works. But I don't know why I can't get it

Comment: Try the same request with the same access token in Graph API Explorer, and see if you get the email there. // You’re aware that the user needs to have the email address verified, otherwise it won’t be returned, and that you won’t _get_ an email for every user, for example if they registered using only their mobile, right?

Comment: It's only a problem with my own email address. Is it possible that it's because of the protection level of my account? :S

Comment: Yes, account privacy settings can influence this in some way, see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298946933534016/ for some more info.

Comment: Ohhh, how silly i am... :D Thank you anyway :) Just I don't experienced it before..

Answer (score 0):

$response->getGraphObject();
to 
$response->getGraphUser();